# Solidity Parson Error Expected Primary Expression

Tags: solidity, defi, modifiers

I'm trying to create a Multi-Sig Wallet in Solidity and I'm following along with a youtube video to do it. He put this snippet of code in the contract:

```
>  modifier txExists(uint _txIndex) {
>     require(_txIndex < transactions.length, "tx does not exist");
>     _;
>      }

modifier notExecuted (uint _txIndex) {
    require(!transactions[_txIndex].executed, "tx already executed");
    _;    
    
}

modifier notConfirmed (uint _txIndex) {
    require(!transactions[_txIndex].isConfirmed[msg.sender], "tx already confirmed");
    _;
}

function confirmTransaction(uint _txIndex) 
public 
onlyOwner
txExists(_txIndex)
notExecuted(_txIndex)
notConfirmed(_txIndex)
{
```

No error returned for him, but for me, it's returning with

```
"Expected primary expression.
modifier txExists(uint _txIndex) {
^------^"
```

I don't know how to solve this for the life of me, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please paste the full code in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com) and come back with a link to that gist.

Comment: if it is only one line then you can put that "require(....)" directly inside the function, probably will also save some gas